# Plot ROC curve of predictive model after internal validation with bootstrap method?

Tags: r, validation, prediction, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

I am currently trying to build a predictive model based on logistic regression. I made ROC curve and calibration plot for the original model with `val.prob.ci()` function from rms package, then I validated the model with `validate(fit, method="bootstrap", B=1000)` from rms package.

I have two questions.

1) Is it correct to get the validated coefficients of independent variables by multiplying the "original" ones by calibration slope?

2) By the function validate I got the validated parameters of the model (c-index, calibration slope, etc). But how to draw ROC curve and calibration plot of this validated model? I would like to use the function `val.prob.ci()` again, because it makes a more complete calibration plot (i.e. with deciles).